# Drupal Views job in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, drupal-7, drupal-views

If anyone was using Drupal, he knows how awesome and powerful its "Views" are. I'm mainly Drupal developer but thinking about learning Symfony2 also. When we are learning new framework, we are often trying to discover new ways of doing old things. Views are awesome because they allows for super fast creating of filterable/sortable data tables. I'm not even dreaming about achieving the same efficiency at creating those kind of tables in Symfony2, but I wonder what the "Symfony2 way" of doing such things is - as person coming to Symfony2 from Drupal. Are there any helping bundles? Is it very easy to achieve "views output" in Symfony2 or it is pretty hard (I would also happily learn about Views specifics - like contextual filters, exposed filters, ajax etc. in context of Symfony2)?

I feel like elaborated answer to this question, would encourage A LOT of Drupal developers to learn Symfony2 (because we are addicted to Views you know ;) ) , which could be very useful in coming Drupal 8 - Symfony2 love affair.

Comment: I guess you are asking the wrong question because there is a difference between a framework and a cms

Comment: Arguably Drupal is also a framework, but I don't have on mind something analogical to Views, what I'm asking for is how can I do Views job in Symfony2 - I know it will be vastly different. Edited the question so it should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 doesn't come with build-in solution for this feature. You could google third-party bundles or implement your own based on ORM (Doctrine2 for example) and javascript data grid library such as [jQuery dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). To bind model data with the frontend view table you can implement ViewTable class that accepts entity name. You also need to define visible, sortable and filterable fields, you could do it either by providing `config` directly to ViewTable class or by entity configuration (Annotation or yaml, xml).